# Can I use git svn in a repository which I cloned using git?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using git to get my Webkit repository by following this:
https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/UsingGitWithWebKit

So I did:

```
git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git WebKit
```

I have been upgrading my repository using "git pull"

My question is: Can I do ' git svn rebase' in my repository? Or I can only do that if I create my repository using this?

```
git svn init -T trunk http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone` checks out a git repository and has no link to SVN, so no. If you want to be linked to an SVN repository, follow the instructions from your link:

> If you are a WebKit committer and want to be able to commit changes to the Subversion repository, or just want to check out branches that aren't contained in WebKit.git, you will need track the Subversion repository. To do that, inform git-svn of the location of the WebKit SVN repository, and update the branch that git-svn uses to track the Subversion repository so that it will re-use the history that we've already cloned from git.webkit.org rather than trying to fetch it all from Subversion:
>
> ```
> cd WebKit
> git svn init -T trunk http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit
> git update-ref refs/remotes/trunk origin/master
> ```

Comment: Thanks. If I create my respostory using 'git svn', will I able to use regular git commands? git status ? git diff? git stash?

Comment: @hap497 Yep. You can use any command that doesn't start with `git svn`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) as an SVN client to avoid those ugly workarounds.